# ifstream Object's .read() Problems of *char

Tags: c++, istream

My code:

```
ifstream Reader ("commands.txt");
if(Reader.fail())
{

    error("File \"commands.txt\" could not be found or opened.\n");

}

Reader.seekg(0, Reader.end);
int FSize = Reader.tellg();

if(FSize == 0)
{

    cout << "File \"commands.txt\" is empty.\n";
    return 0;

}

char * ContentsHold = {};
Reader.read(ContentsHold, FSize);
Reader.close();

string Contents(ContentsHold);
```

The idea is that at the end, Contents should be a c++ string that holds everything in commands.txt. I get the error "basic_string::_S_construct null not valid". I can't figure out what is going wrong. Help?

Comment: `char *` declares a pointer, not an array. If you initialize it with `{}`, that will not create an empty array but will value-initialize the pointer which results in `nullptr`. Why don't you use a `vector<char>` or `string` instead and read into its underlying buffer?

Answer (score 0):

What you have here,

```
char* ContentsHold = {};
```

declares a pointer to character initialized with a null constant. This is not a pointer to the first element of an array, you would have to use the `new[]` syntax for that:

```
char* ContentsHold = new char[FSize];
```

This will create an array and `ContentsHold` will point to its first element. Even better would be to use `std::string` and expose the address of its first element:

```
std::string ContentsHold(FSize);
Reader.read(&ContentsHold[0], FSize);
```

This way you won't have to worry about deleting the new'd memory.